# I want kill app , but my app suspend condition. how can I surely kill app?

Tags: android

If I press the button ,kill app 
but my app suspend condition.
I uses

```
      public void onClick(View v){     
            moveTaskToBack(true);
            finish();
            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        }
    });
}
```

but app is suspend onResume .

Surely , how can I kill app?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do this. In fact, this can get your process marked bad by the system and prevent your app components from running.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
getActivity().finish();
System.exit(0);
```

Or this:

```
finish();
```